# Flexbox и Internet Explorer

Tags: html5, css3, flexbox

Есть родитель, у которого дисплей флекс, три блока внутри схлопываются в IE, понял, что IE для дочерних элементов не вычисляет высоту элементов, каким образом мне можно для IE прописать минимальную высоту ? Поправить это нужно в IE11+

```css
.flex {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

.flex-item {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-item">Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Ipsum рекламных гор единственное о составитель правилами это, на берегу языкового.</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Ipsum реsdsdsкламных гор единственное о составитель правилами это, на берегу языкового.</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбнsdsdые тексты. Ipsum sdsdрекламных гор единственное о составитель правилами это, на берегу языкового.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению флексбоксы в ИЕ не работают, если указать минимальную высоту, попробуйте указать просто высоту, тогда флексбокс будет работать. Не забывайте, что высоту вы можете задавать в разных единицах(`px`, `%`, `em`, `vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax` и функция `calc`), это может вам помочь в зависимости от вашей проблемы.

Прописать стили только для ие11 можно с помощью js например:

```js
navigator.sayswho= (function(){
    var ua=  navigator.userAgent, tem, 
    M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*([\d\.]+)/i) || [];
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+(\.\d+)?)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
    }
    M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]:[navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
    return M.join(' ');
})();


if(navigator.sayswho == 'IE 11.0') {
    document.querySelector('body').className += ' ie11';
}
```

```css
.test {color: red}

.ie11 .test {color: green}
```

```html
<div class="test">text</div>
```

Comment: Могу ли я каким-то образом написать правило только для IE11+ ?

Comment: Добавил код, в IE всё это схлапывается в 1 див, если не задать высоту.

Comment: да, можно написать стили только для ие11, обновила ответ

Comment: да, если не задать высоту будет схалпываться, это написала сразу, но не забывайте, что высоту вы можете задавать в разных единицах(px, %, em, vw, vh, vmin, vmax) и функция calc), это может вам помочь в зависимости от вашей проблемы